# Density of sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem

> Given two random variables of the form $
> f_{X}(x)=a e^{-a x}\mathbf{1}_{x<0}$ and  $f_{Y}(x)=bx e^{-b x}\mathbf{1}_{x<0}$, what is the density of their sum?

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the density of their sum is given by the convolution of their densities.

$$
f_{X+Y}(x)=f_{X} * f_{Y}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(\tau) f_{Y}(x-\tau)d\tau=\int_{0}^\infty ae^{-a \tau}b (x-\tau) e^{-b (x-\tau)}d\tau
$$

$$=\int_{0}^\infty ab (x-\tau) e^{-bx}d\tau$$

However this integral diverges. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The bounds of your convolution integral should be from $\tau=0$ to $\tau=x$.

Comment: Your $X$ and $Y$ are both gamma or Erlang distributions with the same rate of $2$, where $X$ has shape $1$ and $Y$ has shape $2$, so $X+Y$ is also a gamma or Erlang distribution with the same rate of $2$, and with shape $1+2=3$.  With $X_1, X_2,X_3$ being iid samples with the same distribution as $X$, you would have $X_1+ X_2+X_3$ also having this distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are zero for $x < 0$ and $y<0$ respectively. Therefore, when you substitute $ f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ into the integral, the bounds of the integral change to $0$ to $x$.

$\qquad\begin{align}
f_{X+Y}(x)&=[f_{X} * f_{Y}](x)
\\[1ex]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(\tau) f_{Y}(x-\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau
\\[1ex]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2e^{-2 \tau}\mathbf 1_{0\leq\tau}\cdot 4 (x-\tau) e^{-2 (x-\tau)}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x-\tau}\,\mathrm d\tau
\\[1ex]&=8e^{-2x}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x}\int_{0}^x (x-\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau
\\[1ex]&= (8x^2e^{-2x} - 4x^2e^{-2x})\mathbf 1_{0\leq x}
\\[1ex]&= 4x^2e^{-2x}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x}
\end{align}$

Comment: Why do the bounds of this integral go from $0$ to $x$? This is still not clear to me

Comment: Because when (1). tau < 0, then fx(tau) = 0, (2). when tau > x, then fy(x-tau) = 0.